# github action runner showing "idle" and not updating the main website

Tags: github, github-actions

I have been using DigitalOcean: if I change or commit repository the website not being updated.
I am using just one `master` branch, I had 23 file changes but on the site no effects.

here is my action code:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm i
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I change or commit repository the website not being updated.
> I am using just one `master` branch,

First, a change or commits are local actions: you need to push ([`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)) to GitHub in order for any action to have a chance to run.

Second, assuming that you have pushed, but your workflow was not triggered, add a [`on:` directive](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on) (that you have) and double-check your default branch: recent repositories are using `main`, not `master`.

You can see an example in the official GitHub documentation "[Building and testing Node.js / Starting with the Node.js workflow template](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-nodejs#starting-with-the-nodejs-workflow-template)":

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x, 15.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm test
```

Third, if you need to see some effect on a DigitalOcean Droplet, you might need to use [`digitalocean/action-doctl`](https://github.com/digitalocean/action-doctl), in order to deploy (to DigitalOcean) what your GitHub action has build on GitHub side.